# Ubuntu 22.04 Destination host unreachable only on LAN

Tags: networking, server, lan, ping

I'm new to Linux, and I mostly operate my Ubuntu server based on what I find on the internet.

Moving on with my problem, in the last 3 months I made from an old computer a little home lab (jellyfin, PhotoPrism, and a shared folder to move around devices on my LAN). I installed the casaOS web GUI for an easier experience. Everything went OK for those months until the power went off for 2 hours. Nothing to worry about, the computers were off, and nothing was damaged, but the moment I turned on the server I was unable to connect to the server at all, no web GUI, no jellyfin, and no ssh (keep in mind that I use this only locally).

If I ping my computer from the server I get the "Destination host unreachable" message (the same goes if I ping my PC from the server). The thing is that I can ping any other outside website and even the router (192.168.1.1). I assume that this has something to do with my router being off for 2 hours and something changed, but I cannot find what because I didn't make any changes to it. Anyway it's just like it was for the past 2 years.

The way I have this set up is like this:

- I have 1 Windows 10 computer that I use every day, where I try to connect to the server (IP: 192.168.1.3)
- 1 computer with the Ubuntu server (192.168.1.7)
- 1 basic fiber optic router (gateway 192.168.1.1) from my internet provider (where both computers are connected)

I searched the whole internet for the last couple of days, but nothing is working.

Due to the Ubuntu servers being on another computer, I cannot really copy and paste my terminal here (maybe I'll take some photos with my phone), but let me know what information is needed to figure this out.

IP:

[image: ip a picture]

Error on ping:

[image: error on ping]

netplan config:

[image: netplan config]

ping of the gateway:

[image: ping of the gateway]

Comment: Done, i have changed the pictures, sorry about that

Comment: So both computers can ping the gateway IP address of `192.168.1.1` but neither can ping each other? Sounds like a router or switch problem. Did you reboot the router? Can your server reach the internet? Can it ping `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Yep, both computers have access to the internet and can ping outside the network. And yes, I rebooted the router, but nothing happened, and I can't find any option on the router that may block me. What I noticed is that once I rebooted the router i can access the Jellyfin and casaOS web GUIs for the first minute after the connection is established, after that... i lose it

Comment: can someone help me out with this issue?